# View unknown content-types in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, http

A certain URL on my server returns Content-Type: application/json.  The filename ends with .phtml, so whenever I go to it, Firefox 3.5 asks me if I want to save it or open it with another program.  But the answer is neither; I want to view it in Firefox as if it was text/plain.  Suggestions?  The Applications tab of the Preferences window doesn't give this as an option for the "PHTML" type which now is listed in there (ever since I tried to open it with no external program).

Answer (score 1):

There's an addon for that: [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8207).

[image: Screenshot from addon's website]

Answer (score 1):

The JSONView Firefox Plugin will open "application/json" pages inside of firefox instead of asking to download the page. It is a very simple plugin that will give you an easy to read expanded tree view of the JSON. You can then view source and see the plain text.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10869

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do, is prefix the URL with `view-source:`. E.g., for `http://example.com/something.bin` I enter `view-source:http://example.com/something.bin` in the location bar.

I made a bookmarklet with keyword "vs" for it. It either prefixes the current location with `view-source:`, or the location passed by the user. Let me know if you want me to post it.